# Regex not matching all numbers with delimiters

Tags: java, regex, pcre

Need a single combined regex for the following pattern:

```
Prefix: 2221-2720 , Length: 16
Prefix: 51-55 , Length: 16
```

where the delimiters b/w digits can be either space ( ), minus sign (-), period (.), backslash (\), equals (=). The condition being that more than one delimiter (same or different type) can't occur more than once b/w any two digits.

1. Valid number - `230.293.217.952.148.4`
2. Valid number - `230.293 217-952.148.4`
3. Invalid number - `230..293.217.952.148.4`
4. Invalid number - `230.293.-217. 952.148.4`

A valid input is one where you have 16 digits separated by any/no delimiters as long as there are no two delimiters adjacent to each other.

Have come up with the following regex:

```
(2[\s=\\.-]*2[\s=\\.-]*2[\s=\\.-]*[1-9][\s=\\.-]*|2[\s=\\.-]*2[\s=\\.-]*[3-9][\s=\\.-]*[0-9][\s=\\.-]*|2[\s=\\.-]*[3-6][\s=\\.-]*[0-9](?:[\s=\\.-]*[0-9]){1}|2[\s=\\.-]*7[\s=\\.-]*[01][\s=\\.-]*[0-9][\s=\\.-]*|2[\s=\\.-]*7[\s=\\.-]*2[\s=\\.-]*0[\s=\\.-]*)[0-9](?:[\s=\\.-]*[0-9]){11}|(5[\s=\\.-]*[1-5][\s=\\.-]*)[0-9](?:[\s=\\.-]*[0-9]){13}
```

It does not match certain patterns. For example:

1. `2 3 0 2 9 3 2 1 7 9 5 2 1 4 8 4`
2. `23-02-93-21-79-52-14-84`
3. `2 3 0 3 4 5 8 0 9 4 9 3 0 8 2 3`

For the same numbers, it matches (as expected) the following patterns:

1. `2302932179521484`
2. `230.293.217.952.148.4`
3. `2303458094930823`
4. `230.345.809.493.082.3`
5. `230-345-809-493-082-3`

There seems to be an issue with delimiters. Kindly let me know what is wrong with my regex.

Comment: can you make the input shorter(so the regex also shorter), just post minimal question. your problem should not be related to length of regex but specific syntax.

Comment: What's with the repeated `=` in your regex?

Comment: @Blindy = and \ is a valid delimiter too.

Comment: Still not clear what a valid input is and what not. Are only those valid where you have a group of 3 digits separted by a delimeter (first block of example) or also those, where you have 16 digits separted by any/non delimeter as long as there are no two delimeters adjacent to each other (2nd & 3rd block of examples)? What do you mean by **it masks**?

Comment: @Eritrean I meant match instead of mask. A valid input is one where you have 16 digits separated by any/no delimiters as long as there are no two delimiters adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

For this rule

> A valid input is one where you have 16 digits separated by any/no
> delimiters as long as there are no two delimiters adjacent to each
> other
>
> Prefix: 2221-2720 , Length: 16
>
> Prefix: 51-55 , Length: 16
>
> 2221 can also be written as 2.2.-2.1

For these rules, it might be easier to write a pattern with 2 capture groups to match the whole string.

Then using some Java code, you can check the value of the capture groups for the ranges.

```
^((\d[ =\\.-]?\d)[ =\\.-]?\d[ =\\.-]?\d)(?:[ =\\.-]?\d){12}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(\d[ =\\.-]?\d)` Capture **group 2** Match 2 digits with an optional char   `=` `\` `.` `-`
  - `[ =\\.-]?\d[ =\\.-]?\d` Match 2 times optionally 1 of the listed chars and a single digit
- `)` close group 1
- `(?:[ =\\.-]?\d){12}` Repeat 12 times matching one of the  characters and a single digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kk9Y7v/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EqDZw7)

For example

```
String strings[] = { 
        "2221.7.952.148.412.32",
        "230.293.217.952.148.4",
        "5511111111111111",
        "130.293 217-952.148.4",
        "30..293.217.952.148.4",
        "5..5",
        ".5.5."
};

String regex = "^((\\d[ =\\\\.-]?\\d)[ =\\\\.-]?\\d[ =\\\\.-]?\\d)(?:[ =\\\\.-]?\\d){12}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int grp1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
        int grp2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
        
        if ((grp1 >= 2221 && grp1 <= 2720) || (grp2 >=51 && grp2 <= 55)) {
            System.out.println("Match for " + matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match for 2221.7.952.148.412.32
Match for 230.293.217.952.148.4
Match for 5511111111111111
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243283/discussion-on-answer-by-the-fourth-bird-regex-not-matching-all-numbers-with-deli).